# How can I Integrate dialog-polyfill into my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase and [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) in my React app for phone number registration. As you can see at http://brigadesaffinitywebapp-dev.herokuapp.com it works well on Google Chrome desktop but as soon as I try to use another navigator the country code selector doesn't work and throws an error : `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.dialogPolyfill.registerDialog')`. So I guess I need to integrate https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill but I'm having a hard time figuring out how.

I tried to `npm install dialog-polyfill`and then `import dialogPolyfill from 'dialog-polyfill` but I still get the error. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm not currently attaching the instance to the `window`object ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess there is no reasons to complicate things... Just had to put this a the top of index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.7/dialog-polyfill.js"></script>

<script>
  var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
  dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
  // Now dialog acts like a native <dialog>.
  dialog.showModal();
</script>
```

Comment: Just to point out that this is an unwanted behavior in FirebaseUI where the package should include and load dialog-polyfill but it does not apparently : https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/150

Comment: Agree with you but I still downvoted you because you offer a workaround and you don't really provide meaningful explanation as for the why it's not working in OP's question. Also, not every react project provide an index.html